# RandomAccessStream.CopyAndCloseAsync needs Internet?

Tags: c#, uwp, stream, inputstream, outputstream

I have an UWP App here. In this UWP App I'm downloading files. It was noticed that in another country their firewall blocks the download and the UWP App freezes. When debugging on their machine I noticed that after `await RandomAccessStream.CopyAndCloseAsync(inputStream, outputStream);` the UWP App just freezes and the next step never happens in debug mode. You cannot do anything in the UWP App anymore.

I was able to recreate this on my machine by disconnecting from the internet before `await RandomAccessStream.CopyAndCloseAsync(inputStream, outputStream);`. When connecting back to the internet the next step in debug mode happens and the UWP App works just as fine as before.

Now I wonder... what causes this issue? Do I need an Internet Connection for `await RandomAccessStream.CopyAndCloseAsync(inputStream, outputStream);` ? And how can I fix it so it just ignores `await RandomAccessStream.CopyAndCloseAsync(inputStream, outputStream);` this steps?

```
    async public Task DownloadFile(Uri url, string filename)
    {

        Windows.Web.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url, Windows.Web.Http.HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();


        var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsInputStreamAsync();

        IInputStream inputStream = await response.Content.ReadAsInputStreamAsync();         
        StorageFolder folder = await App.GetDocumentFolder();
        StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        IOutputStream outputStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
        await RandomAccessStream.CopyAndCloseAsync(inputStream, outputStream);
    }
```

Comment: Is server on same operating system that you use?  The issue is you are not getting to the end of the stream.  The HTTP webpage is a file on an operating system.   The operating system closed the file when you reach the end which is what the "await"  look for to continue.  I suspect you are not getting a response (or a good) response that causes the hanging.  I would use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and capture the results.  I would compare the TLS version and headers in first request between good and bad locations.  And get the status code in the response which is normally 200 OK.

Comment: Hi @jdweng, I hope I understood you correctly, here is some more information: I literally disconnect from the internet when I reach the breakpoint at 'RandomAccessStream.CopyAndCloseAsync'. Before that breakpoint I already got a good response. When connecting back to the internet the next step after 'CopyAndCloseAsync' is made. I tried 'RandomAccessStream.CopyAsync' - same problem.

Comment: Closing a connection at client doesn't necessarily close the connection at the server.  So you connection is still open at server.  Some server do not allow two connection at same time from same client.  Server know the client by either the cookie or the remote end point (or both).

Comment: @jdweng thank you so far. I think I understand it a little bit better now. But how would I tell the program to close the connection to the server while it is stuck in 'CopyAndCloseAsync'? - In the meantime I also tried 'var ct = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Token; and  'await RandomAccessStream.CopyAndCloseAsync(inputStream, outputStream).AsTask(ct);'

Comment: The transport layer for HTTP is TCP.  Normally when a TCP connection is closed properly and command is sent between client and server so the connection gets closed properly.  When you disconnect an Ethernet cable or simply kill an application the close command does not get sent.  So in your case the client end is closed but not the server.